# Question in Derivation of Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

My question is about an excerpt from Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis, in deriving the heat equation. We have heat, $H(t)$, modelled in terms of temperature at a point $x,y$ at given time $t$, $u(x,y,t)$, for a square $S$ (see below image).

My question is about the last line of the image:

Why does the heat flow through the vertical side have a factor of $h$? Why isn't the heat flow through the vertical side just $- \kappa \cdot \partial_x u(x_0+\frac{h}{2},y_0,t)$? I suppose this is heat flow at a point. In that case, why isn't the heat flow through the vertical side $\int_0^h \kappa \partial_xu(x_0 + \frac{h}{2},y,t)dy$?

[image]

Comment: This is the standard physics derivation of the divergence theorem (in 2D). Since $h$ is small, you approximate your integral by assuming the integrand is constant in $y$. The error is then going to be of higher order in $h$. You're right that they should say "approximately ..." but they have already made it clear they're doing an approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stated that the size of the square is small, implying that the temperature $u$ does not vary significantly over the area of the square and so does does not depend strongly on the coordinates $x, y$. This property was used to derive the second equation, an approximation, in the image you provided. And so, the integral you wrote and the last equation in the image are approximately equal:

$ \kappa \int_0^{h} \partial_x u(x_0 + h / 2, y_0, t) dy \approx \kappa h \partial_x u(x_0 + h / 2, y_0, t)$